# How to get the default encryption settings of amazon S3 buckets via Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, promise, aws-sdk

I'd like to list the default encryption settings(none, AES-256, AWS-KMS) of all my s3 buckets by using the AWS SDK for javascript.(2.305)

First I'm fetching all buckets with listBuckets and then iterate over all buckets with the `getBucketEncryption` function.

My problem is that `getBucketEncryption` is async and therefore I use promises to wait for the processing of all requests. So I add all the promisses to a list and wait for them with `Promise.all()`. Finally when I get all the results, I don't know to which bucket the results belong because `getBucketEncryption` does not return the bucket name with the data and the promisses could resolve in any order.

Somehow I need to wrap a promise around the `s3.getBucketEncryption` call where I can pass the bucketname so that I have it later on for evaluation... but how?

Here comes the code:

```
console.log('Loading function');

const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01', region: 'eu-west-1' });

function reflect(promise){
    return promise.then(
        function(v){ return {cryptSetting:v, status: "COMPLIANT" }},
        function(e){ return {error:e, status: "NON_COMPLIANT"}});
}

s3.listBuckets({},function(err,data){
    if (err){
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    } 
    else{

        var bucketList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.Buckets));

        var list = new Array();

        for(let i in bucketList){
            list.push(s3.getBucketEncryption({Bucket: bucketList[i].Name})
            .promise());      
        }   

        Promise.all(list.map(reflect)).then(function(values) {

            for(let i in values){
                // at this point I do not have the bucket name any more
                // because it's not included in the values array
                console.log("Bucketname missing here " + values[i].cryptSetting
                + ' ' + values[i].status);
            }
          });

     }  
});
```

The output looks like this:

```
Loading function

Bucketname missing here [object Object] COMPLIANT

Bucketname missing here [object Object] COMPLIANT

Bucketname missing here [object Object] COMPLIANT

Bucketname missing here [object Object] COMPLIANT

Bucketname missing here [object Object] COMPLIANT

Bucketname missing here [object Object] COMPLIANT

Bucketname missing here [object Object] COMPLIANT

Bucketname missing here undefined NON_COMPLIANT

Bucketname missing here undefined NON_COMPLIANT

Bucketname missing here [object Object] COMPLIANT

Bucketname missing here undefined NON_COMPLIANT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news ..... it's really simple.

The `values` array is guaranteed to be congruous with the `bucketList` array, regardless of the order in which the promises settled.

So `bucketList[i]` will correspond with `values[i]`.

```
s3.listBuckets({}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    } else {
        var bucketList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.Buckets));
        var promises = bucketList.map(function(b) {
            return s3.getBucketEncryption({ 'Bucket':b.Name }).promise();
        });
        Promise.all(promises.map(reflect)).then(function(values) {
            for(let i in values) {
                // `values` is guaranteed to be congruous with `bucketList`.
                // ie. `bucketList[i]` corresponds with `values[i]`.
                console.log([bucketList[i].name, values[i].cryptSetting, values[i].status].join(' '));
            }
        });
    }  
});
```

Another way would be to :

- move `reflect` up into the `bucketList.map()` stage.
- decorate (in the `bucketList.map(...)` closure) each of the `values` delivered by `reflect()` with a `.bucket` property.

```
s3.listBuckets({}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    } else {
        var bucketList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.Buckets));
        var promises = bucketList.map(function(b) {
            var promise = s3.getBucketEncryption({ 'Bucket':b.Name }).promise();
            return reflect(promise).then(function(value) {
                return Object.assign(value, { 'bucket':b });
            });
        });
        Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
            for(let i in values) {
                // each value now has a '.bucket' property.
                console.log([values[i].bucket.name, values[i].cryptSetting, values[i].status].join(' '));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Both solutions are working fine, I prefer the second one. Thank you.

Comment: Good luck with it StV.